# Individual log file for each thread (Parallel.For) using log4net

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, log4net, parallel.for

I need to create separate log file for each thread being using log4net. 
I am reading multiple mailboxes and want to email information and attachment information of mailboxes in individual files.

```
EmailMaster objEmailMaster = new EmailMaster();
List<MailboxConfiguration> lstMailBoxConfiguration = objEmailMaster.GetMailBoxInformation();

Parallel.For(0, lstMailBoxConfiguration.Count, i =>
{                       
    log.Debug("MailBox reading");    
    objEmailMaster.ReadAndDownloadEmails(lstMailBoxConfiguration[i]);                 
});
```

Comment: Have you already tried something? Which *particular* issues do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary of log by thread like in this proof-of-concept:

```
var ThreadedLogs = new Dictionary<Thread, Log>();

Action<Thread, string> Log = (thread, text) =>
{
  Monitor.Enter(ThreadedLogs);
  if ( !ThreadedLogs.ContainsKey(thread) )
    ThreadedLogs.Add(thread, new Log());
  ThreadedLogs[thread].Debug(text);
  Monitor.Exit(ThreadedLogs);
};

Parallel.For(0, lstMailBoxConfiguration.Count, i =>
{
  Log(Thread.CurrentThread, "MailBox reading");
  objEmailMaster.ReadAndDownloadEmails(lstMailBoxConfiguration[i]);
});

ThreadedLogs.Clear();
```

Comment: do I need to change in config file for log4net setting

Comment: Your code is inefficient. hard to read, and can cause deadlocks. If it's just a proof-of-concept, then you should clearly state that in your answer.